# Где Windows программы хранят данные об триале (реестр, СпецБД)?

Tags: c#, реестр, системное-программирование

1. По моем мнению криптобезопасность триалов держится на игре в прятки. Те где-то отлаживают свои записи, и на этом закрепляются.
2. На примере программы "Bluetooth OBEX File Transfer", в целях учебных, пробовал отслеживать реестр все обращения, смотреть директорию в реестре, дирекекторию в AppData, (1) менять даты обратно, (2) удалять папку в реестре. Но программа стойкая, бесполезно. Как будто в реестре не хранит.
3. Это может быть полезно. Делать свои триальные программы, например я бы хранил в реестре, прятки устроил, песли не известно специальное место.

Comment: я не думаю, что все программы какой то один подход используют, вариантов то миллион

Comment: Каждый разработчик защищает свой софт по-своему. Этот вопрос имеет смысла.

Comment: Все по разному. Видел программы, которые с помощью RPC проверяли данные. Видел системы, которые генерировали ID клиента на основе идентификаторах/серийных номерах используемого оборудования создавали и хранили их в своей базе. Ну или банально давали доступ только зарегистрированным пользователям с подтвержденным номером телефона.

Comment: @aepot Вряд ли здесь кто-то ответит, это вероятно к суперюзерам надо, но вопрос имеет смысл, хотя бы в целях любопытства. И мне кажется, автор вопроса попался на том же, на чем попался однажды я. После форматирования диска и установки лицензионной программы, та сообщила "Срок демо истек" - Это было на компе ни разу не подключенному к интернету. Значит они где-то выделяют область в недоступной памяти ЖД.

Comment: @AlexanderLonberg там нет никакой магии. Типов I/O операций не так много - диск, да сеть. Ну еще Win API есть, реестр например.

Comment: @aepot Так в этом и вопрос, Где остаются данные, если я воткну в комп утилиту, которая полностью отформатирует жесткий диск, с дальнейшей чистой установкой OS системы?

Comment: @МихаилРебров - `Видел программы, которые с помощью RPC проверяли данные.` - А чем здесь может быть полезен RPC?

Comment: Данные о триале могут быть зашиты прямо в исполнимый файл (экзешник).

Answer (score 0):

Поделюсь одной "Игрой в прятки". Речь об устаревших структурах MBR, да и история подустарела.

Часть пользователей столкнулась с проблемой проверки лицензии, другие(в том числе и я) с проблемой обхода блокировки приложений. И все бы ничего, но попытка форматирования диска, с последующей переустановкой системы, приводила в некоторое замешательство - начисто установленная программа прекрасно знала о своей прошлой установке на данном устройстве. И все это на компьютере без подключения к интернету - ни до, ни после переустановки OS.

Как оказалось, компания Nalpeiron(платформа лицензирования), продукты которой используют многие приложения, записывала данные вне файловой системы - [отпечатки нашлись рядом с MBR](https://forums.mydigitallife.net/threads/software-trial-still-expired-after-re-formatting-pc.54409/page-2#post-910808) в строго определенных секторах.

Дальше больше, пользователи легально устанавливающие приложения [получали такие ответы от поддержки - здесь дискуссия, надо кликнуть See more](https://www.proz.com/forum/sdl_trados_support/216143-license_table_altered.html?print=1):

> единственный известный способ исправить эту ошибку —
> выполнить низкоуровневое форматирование

Под низкоуровневым форматированием понималось полное удаление разделов с последующей разметкой. Не смешно, правда. У компании не было утилиты, которая может удалить их же записи прямо из Windows, и вам предлагают снести систему. Партнеры напрочь отказывались выдавать "секрет" и говорили невнятные вещи: *"Мы лицензируем на аппаратном уровне"*.

Энтузиасты конечно нашли сектора записей за пределами тома C:, [то что надо затереть нулями - фотка отсюда](https://nsaneforums.com/topic/302178-nitro-pro%C2%A0enterprise%C2%A01106326%C2%A0-x86x64/page/2/#comment-1265951):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Этот способ, так же помогал разблокировать FreeTrial-версии, те которые на 1-мес, и снова ими пользоваться.

Вот и попробуйте догадайтесь, как форматируя системный C: диск, приложения отказываются вас забывать. Было бы интересно узнать, какие уловки используют сейчас.

Comment: Trial давно признано проигрышной стратегией по сравнению с NPL (некоммерческая лицензия). Триалы с ограничением по времени практически вымерли, а скоро вымрут совсем.

Comment: @aepot Да, это так.